# Find the point that minimises the sum of the angles from three points to that point on the surface of a sphere

Tags: geometry, optimization, triangles, spheres

Let $A,B,C$ be three points on the surface of a unit sphere with centre $O$, such that they are not all three on the same maximal circle.
There is a plane $P$ that contains all three points and on it they define a triangle.
Let $X$ be a point (to be determined) on the surface of the sphere and let $XA$ be the angle between the line segments $OA$ and $OX$ and similarly for $XB$ and $XC$.

**Q1:** Find the point $X$ on the surface of the sphere such that the sum of the three angles $XA+XB+XC$ is minimal.

**Q2:** Is the problem of **Q1** equivalent to finding a point on the plane $P$ that minimises the sum of the (Euclidean) distances from the vertices to that point? (Eg if that point on the plane is found, call it $Y$, then one can extend the line segment from $O$ to $Y$ until the surface of the sphere is intersected)

If one can show that **Q2** is equivalent to **Q1** then the point of minimal sum can be determined by first finding the Fermat point on the plane.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are right of course; I meant _maximal_ circle as you suggested. I will edit the question to clarify that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the angle $\widehat{AOX}$ is proportional to the length of the shortest path (geodetic) between $A$ and $X$ on the sphere, the point $X$ is the spherical analogue of Fermat's point. [The euclidean construction of the Fermat point](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/fermat_point.shtml) just relies on the properties of geodetics and their interactions with isometries, so, in order to find $X$, one is tempted to follow these steps:

1. Let $B'$ be the image of $C$ under a counter-clockwise rotation around $A$ with amplitude $60^\circ$;
2. Let $A'$ be the image of $B$ under a counter-clockwise rotation around $C$ with amplitude $60^\circ$;
3. $X$ is ($\color{red}{\large ?}$) given by the intersection between the $BB'$ geodetic and the $AA'$ geodetic.

However, this approach does not really work, because if $X_A$ is the image of $X$ under a counter-clockwise rotation around $A$ with amplitude $60^\circ$, while the geodetic distance between $A$ and $X$ is the same as the geodetic distance between $A$ and $X_A$, the geodetic distance between $X$ and $X_A$ may be different: in spherical geometry an isosceles triangle with a vertex angle of $60^\circ$ is not always a equilateral triangle, and that is a key point of the Fermat-Torricelli construction.

I do not even expect some straightforward work-arounds, since

1. Due to different Gaussian curvatures, there is no isometric embedding in the plane of a spherical triangle;
2. The locus of points $P$ on a sphere such that the sum between the geodetic distances $PA,PB$ is constant is a quite complicated object.

At the very least, we have a negative answer to **Q2**: our problem **is not** completely equivalent to its euclidean analogue. Anyway, [it was recently solved](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3618527?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) through Lagrange's multipliers: for sufficiently small spherical triangles $ABC$, the spherical Fermat point $X$ is the point such that the angles $\widehat{AXB},\widehat{BXC},\widehat{CXA}$, intended as angles between geodetics, all equal $120^\circ$: that property is shared also by the euclidean Fermat point.

Comment: Thank you for the very informative answer. I haven't carefully read the paper you mentioned yet but could you please explain a bit more 1 and 2 from the second part of your answer?